# Mirror Symmetry vs "Flipping" in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, symmetry

This is an absolutely rudimentary question but I want to get clear from the off with my study of Group Theory.

If we have a rectangular object that can physically be picked up, but which we are using to represent a 2d rectangle, comparing picking it up and "flipping" it by 180° about its vertical or horizontal axis with applying "mirror symmetry" about those axes:

1. Are these actions functionally equivalent?
2. Is there ever a need to distinguish between them?

Comment: What is the definition of mirror symmetry? Is it a group action?

Comment: They are equivalent as long as the object represents a 2D rectangle, and not equivalent otherwise.